# IMAX ratio on 16:9 TVs

Tags: imax, aspect-ratio, sully

The film Sully was shot in part in IMAX or 1.90:1, but it was later cropped to 2.39:1 for Blu-ray. Would the IMAX ratio look funny on 16:9?

I'm having trouble picturing it. I never have been good at picturing aspect ratios in my head!

Will Dunkirk be cropped too?

Comment: What do you mean by  "look funny"? They generally just put black bars at the top, so you end up with a good amount of black space on your screen. If it helps, 16:9 is 1.78:1... it's easier to compare that way.

Comment: Like I mean, how come for Blu-ray, they don't just leave it in 1.90:1? Would that look stupid? Is there a reason they crop it?

Comment: Because the *actual* aspect ratio of the film was 2.39:1... it was cropped for IMAX, not the other way around.

Comment: But how can you get more picture with IMAX if it was shot in 2.39:1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a comparison:

[image: Aspect Ratios]

Red is 16:9 like an HD television. Blue is 1.9:1 like IMAX. Green is 2.39:1 which is what it was filmed at and what the Blu-ray DVD is displayed at. So for 1.9:1 you'd have some small black bars. On a 1920 x 1080 television, the black bars would be roughly 35 pixels on the top and bottom. For 2.39:1, the black bars would be roughly 276 pixels on the top and bottom.

Whether Dunkirk will be cropped or not is up to the studio that produced it.

Comment: Dunkirk was shot with 70mm IMAX film. So it's 1.4:1 so it will definitely be cropped on any TV